# Watson knowledge studio not return the relation between entities

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-nlu, watson-knowledge-studio

I am working on Watson Knowledge Studio and have built a custom model on it. I have declared many relations for my documents and all my documents are different. I have successfully deployed the model on the Natural Language Understanding service. After deploying the Watson Knowledge Studio model, it does not return relations.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please double-check that you specify your model id in the `relations` attribute?

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/natural-language-understanding/customizing.html#customizing

Comment: I have checked the model. But few relations were getting. I have checked the JSON result of NLU.Then I have observed in JSON entity type and entity text are mixed. I think that's why relation was no getting.